# Let MySQL users create databases, but allow access to only their own databases

Tags: mysql

I want to have **multiple** a MySQL users to be able to issue commands like

```
CREATE DATABASE dbTest;
```

But I also want each of these users to be able to see and access only their **own** databases.

All I could find was how to either create the databases by a DBA and grant the privileges on this database to the specific user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbTest.* TO 'user';
```

or grant privileges on all databases to a user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user';
```

But neither is what I want, because it needs to scale and be secure.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can use

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testuser\_%` .  * TO 'testuser'@'%';
```

to grant the user `testuser` privileges on all databases with names beginning with `testuser_`.

This allows the testuser to create databases limited to names starting with testuser_

Comment: When running this i'm getting ERROR 1064 ...  right syntax to use near '* TO 'testuser'@'%'' at line 1

Comment: Could you post the entire query?

Comment: I've noticed this only happens when running under `mysql -u root -e "QUERY"` , it works if you escape the backticks with backslashes

Answer (score 26):

You can use

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testuser_%` . * TO 'testuser'@'%';
```

to grant the user `testuser` privileges on all databases with names beginning with `testuser_`.

EDIT: I'm not sure if this user is now also allowed to create databases.

Yes, this allows the `testuser` to create databases limited to names starting with `testuser_`

Comment: I had to wrap backticks around testuser_% but unfortunately in stack overflow that wont come through as backticks signify a code section.

Comment: This should be a comment on Lex's answer, not an answer itself.

Comment: I'm not sure if this user is now also allowed to create databases.... No, it isn't.

Answer (score 17):

Create a stored procedure that is defined by the admin user and invokes with the admin user privileges by using SQL SECURITY DEFINER. In the stored procedure,

- Create the database.
- Set the privileges on the database so only the current user has access.
- Execute FLUSH PRIVILEGES to reload the privileges from the grant tables.

Use [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_user) to get the current user login details.

[Find out more about SQL SECURITY DEFINER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html).

Comment: Where to create the stored procedure. Which database has this stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to do this **using permissions only** .

The workaround as suggested in another answer:
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON`testuser_%`. * TO 'testuser'@'%';`
has the problem that the users must then be very careful in naming their databases.

For example if user `aaa` creates database `bbb_xyz`, it can then be accessed exclusively by user `bbb` but not by user `aaa`.

Comment: I don't catch your meaning... user `aaa` will not be able to create a database `bbb_xyz`, it will **only** be able to create a database called `aaa_xyz`