# Ubuntu 14.04.2 Permission denied while create a new database

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2. i have logged in into mysql by using the below code

```
mysql -u test -p
```

password is password

but I want to create another database,   by using

```
create database test1
```

it shows me the error that is

Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' to database 'test1'

please show me the way how can I create a new database

Comment: does the user 'test' have permission to create schemas?

Comment: Your user seems to be lacking privileges for creating databases. Or, at least, he is not allowed to access the newly created database. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950054/let-mysql-users-create-databases-but-allow-access-to-only-their-own-databases

Comment: how could i set perimission for a user?

Comment: only user which has grant permissions can assign/change permissions, so  either login such a user like root and provide required rights to test user or ask who have such permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Login as a root :

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

create new user :

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Give privileges :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

Exit and now login with new user :

```
sudo mysql -u newuser -p
```

Refer https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql for more details.