# Run MySQL command with accent mark (`) using bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I would like to run a mysql command using a bash script but getting an syntax error because of the accent mark (`).

`` mysql -u root -p -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testuser\_%` .  * TO 'testuser'@'%';" ``

[Let MySQL users create databases, but allow access to only their own databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950054/let-mysql-users-create-databases-but-allow-access-to-only-their-own-databases)

`bash: testuser_%: command not found...
Enter password:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '* TO 'testuser'@'%'' at line 1`

Looks like a bash confuses this part `` `testuser\_%` ``
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the shell world, if you're having trouble with delimiters, add more backslashes:

```
"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`testuser\_%\` .  * TO 'testuser'@'%';"
```

That should fix the issue.

An unescaped ` character means ["execute this command and inline the result"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands).

Answer (score 0):

Escape the backticks, they're used for command substitution in double quotes.

```
mysql -u root -p -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`testuser\_%\` .  * TO 'testuser'@'%';"
```

You can also put the MySQL command in single quotes, then no substitution occurs. You'll need to switch the embedded quotes to double quotes:

```
mysql -u root -p -e 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testuser\_%` .  * TO "testuser"@"%";'
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered, the back-ticks are command-substitution metacharacters to the shell—but that's only true if you put them inside a double-quoted string.

So the simplest solution is to put them inside a single-quoted string instead:

```
mysql -u root -p -e 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testuser\_%` .  * TO testuser@%;'
```

Notice that I omitted the quotes around the user@host. You don't need them in this case. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html says:

> The user name and host name need not be quoted if they are legal as unquoted identifiers. Quotes are necessary to specify a user_name string containing special characters (such as space or -), or a host_name string containing special characters or wildcard characters (such as . or %); for example, 'test-user'@'%.com'.
>
> Quote user names and host names as identifiers or as strings, using either backticks (`), single quotation marks ('), or double quotation marks (").