# Run MySQL command with accent mark (`) using PowerShell

Tags: mysql, powershell

I would like to run a mysql command using a Powershell but getting an syntax error because of the accent mark (`).

`` mysql -u root -p -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testuser\_%` .  * TO 'testuser'@'localhost';" ``

`` mysql : ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\_'.
At line:1 char:1
+ mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testuser\_%`.* TO  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\_'.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError ``

Looks like a Powershell confuses this part `` `testuser\_%` `` or `\_%` Any suggestions?

[Let MySQL users create databases, but allow access to only their own databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950054/let-mysql-users-create-databases-but-allow-access-to-only-their-own-databases)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the backtick

> `

is the literal escape character in PowerShell.

You can get around this by using *single quotes* to define your string

> '

How about doing this?

```
$query = 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testuser\_%` .  * TO testuser@localhost'
mysql -uroot -p -e "$query"
```