# Create database permission to user - Mysql access previleges

Tags: mysql

I want to create multiple users on MySQL and allow them to create databases and access the databases which are only created by them. Is there a way to do this?
If so what permission I need to give?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950054/let-mysql-users-create-databases-but-allow-access-to-only-their-own-databases/2950156](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950054/let-mysql-users-create-databases-but-allow-access-to-only-their-own-databases/2950156)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving "create database" permission to a user, from "root" you can just create the database and grant all privileges on the database to the specific users. That's what I am using in my world. I don't think "create database" privileges available in MySQL especially.

Using the below approach you have the control of database level because the user can do anything in the specific database where they had the permission, not at the instance level (mean they can't create junk databases).

```
Friday 28> mysql -uroot -p
mysql> create user test identified by 'test';
mysql> create database x1;
mysql> grant all privileges on x1.* to 'test'@'%';

Friday 28> mysql -utest -p
Enter password: 

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| x1                 |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use x1;
Database changed
mysql> create table test(c int);
seQuery OK, 0 rows affected (0.44 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```