# Grant all privileges on set of databeses with same prefix

Tags: mysql

I have a set of databeses with names like abc_base_1, abc_base_2, abc_base_3 abc_base_n.

I'd like to grant all privileges on all tables of all this databases to one non root user.

Generally, it seems that abc_ is a common prefix of group.

Questions:

1. Is mysql has database groups? If yes - how to define them (something special or it just has to have same name prefix (like abc))?
2. Is it possible to grant privileges on group of databases (or databases with names starts with abc prefix)? If yes - how to grant?
3. Is this permissions distributes dynamically for all new databases, that has the same name prefix or I should grant permissions all the time, when new databases are created.

Comment: 1. No 2. No 3. No

Comment: You should normalize all those tables into one table. Modern SQL servers can handle millions or billions of records in one just just when indexed and the tables are designed correctly...

Comment: You could write a script to do it, but that woudl have inherant security issues as you would have to use an account with GRANT privilages and PHP code is so easily read

Comment: i also wonder how MySQL and PHP will handle prepared statements with `GRANT` statements, i've ever tryed or used it @RiggsFolly

Comment: Good point @RaymondNijland neither have I. But OP does not have to use PHP i suppose :) I bet you could write a stored proceedure to do it, or a bash/batch script

Comment: ok no PHP right, but check [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hLvxzxDdFANj98tRS3Cvwo/0) @RiggsFolly pretty sure you also can't do this in a SP right or anny programming language for that matter.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Well phpMyAdmin manages it, so I have to assume its not impossible

Comment: phpMyAdmin cheats most likely with a whitelist there.. wait a moment i found a way in the past to "hack" in safe (atleast it past mine SQL injection tricks) `CREATE TABLE` statements with `prepare` which would be user input.. need to search @RiggsFolly yes [found](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ai83gaMJMJ7tRFLtTSzyzt/18) it  pretty sure this can be rewritten to allow SQL injection safe `GRANT` queries also.. But it can error with SQL keyword but a live application would not show database parse errors it's not injectable

Comment: It's a valid question. AFAIK Postgre has something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can grant permissions to a group of MySQL databases identified by a `LIKE` wildcard:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON `abc\_%`.* TO username@localhost;
```

Permissions are checked when a user attempts to access the database -- you do not need to repeat this `GRANT` statement when databases are created.

Comment: At first i believe that this will would not work because i never saw it before then i looked in the documentation there was the very small text explaining without a example your can mis it in the manual.. +1 for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950054/let-mysql-users-create-databases-but-allow-access-to-only-their-own-databases).

Privileges should be granted like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `abc\_%` .  * TO 'someuser'@'localhost';
```

This expression provides the following rights:

- access to all databases started with `abc_`
- create new databases, started with `abc_`
- access to new databases, started with `abc_` but created by other users.