# Allowing Users To create databases with permissions for themselves only

Tags: mysql

I need for my users to create databases that only they can select,add,drop tables to.
I saw this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950054/let-mysql-users-create-databases-but-allow-access-to-only-their-own-databases) which is exactly what I need but when I run command as

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testuser\_%` .  * TO 'testuser'@'LOCALHOST';
```

I get error

```
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'testuser' on host 'localhost'
```

I googled error and tried Flush Privileges but still get error. Any suggestions welcomed. I am running Ubuntu 16.4 w/mysql 5.7.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't grant all privileges to a wildcard selector for end users. In all reality, they'd pick a database name, your backend application would set it up, and grant privileges to only _their_ user on that one specific database.

Comment: how would you implement this/

Comment: It really depends on the purpose behind what you're doing. Overall granting end-user access to a database backend (in any form) is almost exactly last on my list of recommendations.

Comment: I need to create a sort of sandbox for these users so they can only perform operations on databases they create.