# Problem to create two databases with doctrine in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm working on a Symfony project, using doctrine as ORM with MariaDB as a driver.

To test my different job, I'm working with gitlab-runner in local on MacOs.

## Problem

I create a job to test the creation of my different databases and the migrations for both.

I'm using the symfony-cli command line to create my databases from the doctrine's file configuration (see in the section Source File)

The command line to create a database with symfony-cli

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=test --if-not-exists --connection=[CONNECTION_NAME]
```

The error prompt when the command line from is asked to run

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=test --if-not-exists --connection=CleanerFuture
Could not create database `cf_CleanerFuture` for connection named CleanerFuture
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE DATABASE `cf_CleanerFuture`':

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'myapptest'@'%' to database 'cf_CleanerFuture'
```

## Goal

Well my goal it's to try to create the database base with this command line to run my job and past to the next one

## Source File

### .gitlab-ci.yml

This is the job I try to execute

```yaml
doctrine-migrations:
  image: php:7.3
  stage: Migrations
  services:
    - name: mysql:5.7
      alias: mysql
  variables:
    ENV: test
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass_test
    MYSQL_DATABASE: cf_Central
    MYSQL_USER: myapptest
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: myapptest
    DATABASE_URL: 'mysql://myapptest:myapptest@mysql:3306/'
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y git libzip-dev
    - curl -sSk https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --disable-tls && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
    - docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip
    - curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash
    - mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
    - composer remove ext-xdebug
    - composer install
  script:
    - php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force --if-exists --env=test --connection=default
    - php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force --if-exists --env=test --connection=CleanerFuture
    - php bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=test --if-not-exists --connection=CleanerFuture
    - php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --env=test
  allow_failure: false
```

#### config/test/doctrine.yaml

```yaml
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
      default:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%cf_central'
        server_version: "mariadb-10.4.11"
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        charset: utf8
      CleanerFuture:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%cf_CleanerFuture'
        server_version: "mariadb-10.4.11"
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        charset: utf8
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
      default:
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        connection: default
        mappings:
          Central:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Central'
            prefix: 'App\Entity\Central'
      CleanerFuture:
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        connection: CleanerFuture
        mappings:
          Client:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Client'
            prefix: 'App\Entity\Client'
```

Comment: Most likely, while your database user can create talbes, it doesn't have the rights to create the database itself. Please refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950054/let-mysql-users-create-databases-but-allow-access-to-only-their-own-databases

Comment: `1044 Access denied for user 'myapptest'@'%' to database 'cf_CleanerFuture'`  - what have you tried to resolve that error?

Comment: yes, i had resolve it by creating the database by commande line instead of symfony cli

Answer (score 0):

`url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%cf_CleanerFuture'` in your `config/test/doctrine.yaml` file:

The part `cf_CleanerFuture` will be added to the string value of the variable `DATABASE_URL` which is defined in your `.env` file.

If your `.env` file value for the datbase connection contains something like

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://symfony:symfony@database:3306/symfony?serverVersion=8.0"
```

the processed content of your config will be

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
      default:
        url: 'mysql://symfony:symfony@database:3306/symfony?serverVersion=8.0cf_central'
```

`'mysql://symfony:symfony@database:3306/symfony?serverVersion=8.0cf_central'` seems to be valid (doctrine can connect and the parameter `serverVersion` will be ignored if not usable), but the value of the parameter `serverVersion` is now `8.0cf_central`. That makes no sense, is not a valid version number and you haven't configured a different database connection.

It is more recommended to use two different environment variables and store the whole connection URL in these variables:

```
# config/packages/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
            customer:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_CUSTOMER_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
```

See also the Symfony documentation which describes how to configure multiple database connections: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html